# Converting an audio file to a midi of the drums

Tags: cubase, automation

Is there any tool which get as input a song (some audio file) and outputs the drums of the song to a midi file or any file that can be opened by Cubase?

My goal here is to record a song with me playing the bass and guitars and having the drums extracted and implemented automatically from the original to my cover version.

Is there any tool to help with this task?

Comment: What research have you done so far? What have you found? Why wasn't it suitable?

Comment: I could only find tools that take drums audio and translate to midi, but seems like it won't work with the extra noise of the song unless it is designed for it. I also don't have enough knowledge in sound to make a proper research, was hoping for any help on similar tools that might be helpful if there is no tool exactly for this.

Comment: The simple answer is No, as you have already discovered, there is no tool that will do this. When there are other instruments in the audio, it is not a simple task to identify drums accurately.

Comment: tbh, it would be quicker to just play it in. 20 minutes to learn it, two takes to play it. The 'trick' for playing "keyboard drums" is on the first pass imagine the kick drum, then do a second pass to add it.